# initial point in CORDIC algorithm

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods, cordic, elementary-functions

I am trying to reduce number of iterations required to calculate multiplication using the CORDIC algorithm because I am using this algorithm in a continuous function to calculate square function. Here is the algorithm assuming `-1<x<1'`

```
function z=square(x)
 y=x;
 z=0;
  for i=1:15
    if (x > 0)
      x = x - 2^(-i);
      z = z + y*2^(-i);
    else
      x = x + 2^(-i);
      z = z - y*2^(-i);
    end
  end
return
end
```

I already know the close value to multiplication result (from the previous result (call it `pr`)) and value of `x` (the value of x is continuous) . Does it help in anyway to decrease number of iterations?

Answer (score 1):

If you are multiplying twice by the same constant, say `a.x` and `a.x'`, then you can multiply and add with the delta `a.(x' - x)`, which has less significant digits.

In case both factors vary, you can still use

```
x'.y' = (x'- x).(y' - y) + x.(y' - y) + (x' - x).y + x.y
```

where maybe the first term is neglectible.

For a square,

```
x'² = (x'- x)² + 2.x.(x' - x) + x²
```